# how to use Numba target='parallel' to check if a 2D array exists in a list which comprises of multiple 2D arrays

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I use `Ip` & `N` to explain my question.

```
Ip1 = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) #2D array

N = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ] # list of 2D arrays:[ Ip1, Ip2, Ip3 ]

print(len(N)) # len of N = 3
```

I want to write a numba code that will check if `Ip` exists in a big `N` list in parallel on multiple CPU cores.

The code that I tried is:

```
@staticmethod
@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64[:,:], int64[:,:,:])], '(m),(p,p),(m,p,p)', target='cpu')
def IP_in_N(NequaltoIP, IP, N):
    for n in N:  
        if (n == IP).all(): #if IP is found in N then NequaltoIP=1
            NequaltoIP += 1
```

It will generate an array `NequaltoIP` which is of same dimension as the length of `N`. This code runs fine but gives error when `target='parallel'`.

Is there a way to write it using `@guvectorize` or `@jit` and make it run on multiple CPU cores in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it like this:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:,:], nb.int64[:,:,:], nb.int64[:])], '(m,m),(n,m,m)->(n)', target='parallel')
def IP_in_N(IP, N, res):
    for idx in range(len(N)):  
        res[idx] = (IP == N[idx]).all()
```

This returns:

```
>>> IP_in_N(Ip1, N)
array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

This returns an array where `1` indicates a match and `0` a not-match. So you need to use `np.sum` to get the number of matches:

```
>>> np.sum(IP_in_N(Ip1, N))
1
```

---

The reason why you couldn't use it in parallel was that your approach didn't use a target (your signature doesn't have a `->`). That makes it impossible to find the dimension along which to "parallelize" the computation. Note that to parallelize the computation the problem needs to be "chunkable", so you **need** an array in which to write. You shouldn't use any globals or counters when you want parallel execution.

However you won't be faster just by throwing more cores at this problem, because it's just doing equality testing which is memory-bandwidth limited. Most of the time your CPUs will just wait for the data from the RAM. And by parallel execution you essentially only added bookkeeping overhead. Compare this to a "naive" numpy solution:

```
Ip1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) #2D array

# N with 90000 2x2 inner arrays
N = np.array([ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ] * 30000)

%timeit np.sum(IP_in_N(Ip1, N))
14.1 ms ± 96.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.sum(np.all(Ip1 == N, axis=(1, 2)))
2.41 ms ± 87.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```